# Solving improper integrals with residual theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble applying residual theorem when solving integrals that involve something like $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ or $e^x.$ Could I get some advice on where my approach might have been wrong?

For example the following has the solution $\frac{-\pi \sin\left(2\right)}{3e^6}$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{x^2+2x+10}\,dx.$$

My approach is to first find the poles, which I think is only when the denominator is zero, at $x=-1+3i,-1-3i$. Then I only choose to find the residue at the root that is above real axis:

$$\lim _{z\to -1+3i}\left(z+1-3i\right)\left(\frac{\sin\left(2z\right)}{\left(z+1-3i\right)\left(z+1+3i\right)}\right)$$

Then to work around the $\sin$ I change it to $e^{2iz}:$

$$\lim _{z\to -1+3i}\left(\frac{e^{2iz}}{\left(z+1+3i\right)}\right)=\frac{ie^{-6-2i}}{6}$$

Then:
$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{x^2+2x+10}\,dx=2\pi i\left(\frac{ie^{-6-2i}}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi \:e^{-6-2i}}{3},$$

which looks close but I am not sure if this is actually the right answer and that I just need to some how convert part of the exp back to sin.

Comment: What is your full contour?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I think it would the |z| which is a semi circle with radius $sqrt(10)$ right?

Comment: That's not what I would use. Remember that, when setting up your contour, you need part of it to match the real integral you're trying to compute. So I would have two parts: $\gamma_1: [-R,R]$ on the real axis, then the semi-circle back: $\gamma_2: Re^{i\theta},\; 0\le\theta\le\pi.$ This would enclose the pole in the upper-half plane. You might need to use the $ML$ inequality to show that, in the limit as $R\to\infty,$ the semi-circle piece goes to zero (hopefully).

Comment: The manipulations you show us here look like you think $\sin(t)=e^{it}$. In fact (for real $t$)  $\sin(t)=\Im e^{it}$.  Insert "$\Im$" in a few places and you get the right answer.